# Reference request: $\ell^1$, $\ell^2$, $\ell^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I would like to recive from you some references (books and or good notes) about the spaces $\ell^p$. I have searched over here already, but I really didn't find any good match to what I am asking for.

What I would like, is some good reference about a deep treatise on the spaces $\ell^n$. I would like some reference that study in a rather complete way the meaning and the applications of the spaces $\ell^n$ with particular focus on $p = 1$, $p = 2$, $p = 0$, $p = +\infty$, explainin their meaning, their applications, how to deal with them when it's about sequences and convergence questions and so on.

I don't really know how to make myself clear, and I am sorry...

What I am trying to tell is that the most of the textbooks seems to avoid or to really shorten the treatise of those spaces, in favour of $L^p$ spaces. I understand they might be more useful and cooler though.

I never saw, so far, books or notes dedicated to $\ell^p$ spaces, with great examples and applications, so I am here, hoping that someone of you had my same curiosity an found something cool already.

Thank you!

Comment: These are indeed rare. This might be because $\ell^p = L^p(\mathbb{N}, 2^{\mathbb{N}}, \zeta)$ if $\zeta$ is the counting measure. Alt - Linear Functional Analysis at least goes a tiny little bit in depth. But not too much as well. The book is a bit weirdly structured so you will find bits all over the book

Answer (score 3):

Try [Lindenstrauss & Tzafriri](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387080724) volume I

Answer (score 0):

Some chapters in [Topics in Banach Space Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/0-387-28142-8) by Albiac and Kanton focus on the $\ell^p$ spaces.